Is it necessary to include non-analytical correction in the phonon calculations for intrinsically dipoled monolayers?
Good day, Is it necessary to include non-analytical correction (using Born effective charges and dielectric constants tensors) in the phonon calculations for 2D materials that is intrinsically dipolar with distinct top and bottom surfaces as shown below?

The phonon dispersion with and without correction looks like the following

While going through the literature, I have found the following statement, "Theories predict that the LO-TO splitting will breakdown in two-dimensional (2D) polar systems" .
Practically, the DFT-calculated phonon dispersion show some splitting of LO-TO when correction is applied. Is it just an artifact? Some explanation will be very much appreciated.

Following your reference, they claim a different non-analytic term is required for 2D compared with 3D systems. Which is implemented/ have you used? If using a 3D non-analytic term for the 2D case, it might explain why you seem to "recover" 3D behaviour in a 2D system?
